# Can't remove whitespace in rythm engine

Tags: rythm

I am using the [rythmengine](http://rythmengine.org/).

The output I want is: `x=prefix:value` without any whitespaces.

```
@def test(String param){
@{param="prefix:"+param} @param
}
1
2  x=@test("value")
3
```

output is: `2 x= prefix:value`

```
@def test(String param){
@{param="prefix:"+param}@param
}
1
2  x=@test("value")
3
```

output is: `2 x=param`

This seems like a bug. Does anyone know a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code on http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/#/editor:

`@def test(String param){
@{param="prefix:"+param}@@param
}
1
2  x=@test("value")
3`